# Hive or Pig dynamic table

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Can any body help me creating dynamic tables in hive or pig by passing data type and column name dynamically.

Thanks in advance

Trisha

Answer (score 0):

Create Table syntax can be seen here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/TruncateTable